# Python: Different R-squared values from summary and r_squared function

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am building a multiple linear regression model using the following:

```
regressor = sm.OLS(y_train, X_train).fit()
```

When requesting a summary of the model with `regressor.summary()`, the R-squared is **0.204**. However, when using `r2_score(y_test, y_pred)` I get **0.023**.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`regressor.summary()` is giving r2 for training data
while `r2_score(y_test, y_pred)` is giving r2 for testing data